# How to use moment library inside a Vue.js component

Tags: vuejs2, momentjs

After, `yarn add moment`

I tried...

```
import moment from 'moment'
Vue.prototype.moment = moment
```

&

```
import moment from 'moment'
Vue.use(moment)
```

&

```
var moment = require('moment');
Vue.use(moment)
```

Nothing really works. I am getting all kinds of weird error msgs!

Can anyone tell, how to use moment library with Vue.js 2?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally, it works!

call`moment()` from inside Component's `methods` block.

Sample usage:-

```
<template>
<v-ons-page>
  <p>{{isToday("12-02-1980")}}</p>
</v-ons-page>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'

export default {
methods: {
        isToday(date) {
            return moment(date).isSame(moment().clone().startOf('day'), 'd');
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that when using TypeScript, it was necessary to use

**import * as moment from 'moment'**

Sample:

```
<template>
<div id="sample">
    <span>{{ formatDate("11-11-2011") }}</span>
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import * as moment from 'moment'

@Component()
export default class Sample extends Vue {

    formatDate(d) : string {
        return moment(d).format("MMM Do YYYY");
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to import Moment in every vue component, so I went with an approach that is described in this article: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/

```
import Moment from 'moment';
Moment.locale( 'de' );
Object.defineProperty( Vue.prototype, '$moment', { value: Moment });
```

Now you can use Moment in your components, ie.:

```
   methods : {

        date : function( timestamp ) {

            return this.$moment( timestamp ).format( 'LLL' );

        }

    }
```